# addchild from externally loaded swf in Air project

Tags: actionscript-3, air, flash, external

I am working on an Air app for iOS and looking for a way to load an external swf and then add/remove the movieclips in that library to the main stage.

Normally, I can use an addchild routine in the document class of the external swf which I can access from the main document class. But since document classes in externally loaded swfs are not allowed in Air deployment, I can't use this method.

Each external swf will contain up to 10 separate movieclips and there are over 25 external swf's I want to load in/remove from the main stage, all containing unique artwork/animation.

Can anyone please suggest a way to do this?
THANKS!
matt

Answer (score 1):

I had same problem i also had around 10 different external swfs with code. So the easiest way for me was to compile every file to swc and included them after in project.

Comment: Were you loading them remotely or were they bundled in your app?

Comment: Swc's were bundled in app. And sorry for late response.